# My mod_wsgi web app isn't running another script

Tags: python, linux, r, web-applications, mod-wsgi

I am a novice at web development, and I'm trying to create a simple mod_wsgi app that calls an R script that will write some text to a .txt file, then mod_wsgi reads that file and displays it on the webpage.  The python and R code work when I execute manually at the command line, but when I try to integrate it with my web app it doesn't execute the R script at all so no .txt file is generated for the web app to read.  That is causing a 500 error.

I'm passing some command-line arguments to the R script with os.system(), but like I said before, the R script is not getting executed:

```
a=2
b=3    
commandString = "/home/usr/bin/R --no-save --quiet --slave --args " + str(a) + " " + str(b) + " <webcalc.R"
os.system(commandString)
f=open('/home/usr/webapps/simple/htdocs/prob.txt','r')  #This is the file that the R script was supposed to write.
prob=f.read(2)
prob=str(prob)+'%'
f.close()
```

I'm using an Apache server.  Here is the exact error I get from my error log:

```
[Mon Jul 23 17:45:42 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=10367): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/usr/webapps/simple/htdocs/index.py'.
[Mon Jul 23 17:45:42 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Jul 23 17:45:42 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/usr/webapps/simple/htdocs/index.py", line 88, in application
[Mon Jul 23 17:45:42 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     f=open('/home/usr/webapps/simple/htdocs/prob.txt','r')
[Mon Jul 23 17:45:42 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/usr/webapps/simple/htdocs/prob.txt'
[Mon Jul 23 17:45:42 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /home/usr/webapps/simple/htdocs/favicon.ico
```

I'm sure this is a very simple problem but I can't find a solution anywhere.  I really appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: It says: `No such file or directory: '/home/usr/webapps/simple/htdocs/prob.txt'`, so are you sure your R script is creating that file? Is it there when you look in the `home/usr/webapps/simple/htdocs` directory?

Comment: Don't use os.system. [Use the `subprocess` module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html)

Comment: The R script definitely is not creating the file, but I'm almost sure it's because the R script is not getting run in the first place.  When I manually place a "prob.txt" file of my creation in the directory, the mod_wsgi script works perfectly and displays whatever I put in the prob.txt file.  However the issue is I want the R script to create that .txt file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IMPORTANT: THIS IS NOT PROTECTED AGAINST MALICIOUS INPUT**

```
import subprocess
a=2
b=3
commandString = "/home/usr/bin/R --no-save --quiet --slave --args " + str(a) + " " + str(b) + " < /path/to/webcalc.R"
# This is BAD PRACTICE, but necessary in this instance,
# if my assumptions of R are correct.
retval = subprocess.call(commandString, shell=True)
```

Unless your R interpreter (or whatever it is) can accept a filename directly instead of using input redirection, you must pass a string to subprocess.call() and use shell=True, which is a Bad Thing (tm).

You should also specify the input script by absolute path, not relative, as I've done in the example.

Comment: Your fixes worked!

Also, I don't understand what you meant by input redirection.  Could you explain what you mean by "...accept a filename directly instead of ...input redirection" and what the ideal alternative would be?  Thanks so much for your help, Colin.

Comment: @user1385991 looking at the [R manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/r), it looks like you have to use `<` for input files and `>` for output files. Check out [this page on bash I/O redirection](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html). Ideally you would just give the R interpreter the script's filename (like you do with python) instead of the redirection. With redirection, you're telling the shell to do something like this: `cat myRscript.r | /usr/bin/R --somearg`.

Comment: is it possible to give the R script command-line arguments without using input redirection?

Comment: @user1385991 I have no idea, I've never used R.